# How to define date and time using Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework-4

Datetime usually is define as datetime.

What if I want a column for just date and another column for time?

Can I define [date] or [time]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Out of the box - no. While sql has datatypes date and time you can extend entity framework http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd456844(v=vs.100).aspx with datatypes [Date] and [Time] or implement logic splitting DateTime in two values.